# How do you render a closed surface double integral?

Tags: support, mathjax

In other words, this:

[image: double loop integral]

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_symbol), the code is `\oiint`, but it doesn't seem to work on this site.

Comment: I think $$\oint$$ is just ok for alternative. I have seen such notation on Griffith's electromagnetics book, where $\oint$ integral applies to both loops and closed surfaces, sometimes even bulks.  After all, you can tell from the $d$ part, or the particular context whether the integral is a line, surface or a bulk one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is off topic because it pertains to [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org), which is a third party extension for rendering TeX on websites. Nonetheless, I'll answer it for you.

---

MathJax does not support this command. You will have to use the unicode directly, using the `\unicode` command. A table of relevant unicode commands is [here](http://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=INTEGRAL); the one you seek can be obtained by `\unicode{x222F}`: $\large\unicode{x222F}$.

A list of commands MathJax supports is available on their site, namely [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands).

Comment: It's important to add: the MathJax webfonts do not contain the unicode character. Therefore, this relies on the hope that the reader happens to have a font installed that contains this character (such as the STIX fonts). Typesetting quality will be a bit lower with such fallback character (though not with the STIX fonts)

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Good point, thanks. I've been using the STIX fonts for so long that I start forgetting about that non-obvious influence on my MathJax experience.

Comment: I can relate :) on the bright side, we're adding a number of new fonts in the next MathJax release, including STIX webfonts, so this will be less of a problem (assuming stackexchange chooses to switch to STIX webfonts which are larger.)

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I wonder what you think of the alternatives in my answer and the comments below it.

Answer (score 4):

Using @Ruslan's suggestion based on [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5963/21441),
I came up with these for both double and triple closed integrals:

```
\newcommand{\oiint}{{\subset\!\supset} \llap{\iint}}
\newcommand{\oiiint}{{\large{\subset\!\supset}} \llap{\iiint}}
```

which display as
$$
{\subset\!\supset} \llap{\iint}_{\partial \Omega}{dS}
$$
and
$$
{\large{\subset\!\supset}} \llap{\iiint}_{\partial H}{dV}
$$
respectively.

Comment: `{\iint\hspace{-27px}{\subset\!\supset}}`

Answer (score 2):

> **Edit:** Take this answer with a grain of salt. The positioning of the circles is patchy and appears to be platform-dependent. Thus, even if it looks OK in your system, it may look off-centre in other setups.

---

You can always try to make one yourself. For example,

```
\bigcirc \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\iint_S
```

will produce
$$\bigcirc \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\iint_S$$

This works in displayed equations and is better for that than using unicode as in [Lord_Farin's answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9975/30935) because it scales better: the latter produces 
$$\unicode{x222F}$$
On the other hand, I have not found an appropriate circle command to use inline for the direct approach.

Comment: $$\bigcirc\kern-1.4em\iint_Sf(x,y)\mathrm d\ xy$$ looks much better.

Comment: Or $$\bigcirc\hspace{-14pt}\iint$$

Comment: @AsafKaragila, this is the first time I saw the notation $\mathrm{d}\ xy$.  I usually see $\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$.

Comment: For me, these circles are off-center.

Comment: @Joel: This is the first time I wrote an integral for quite a long while now. Even longer for double integrals.

Comment: @GEdgar, could you take a screenshot to show how far off-center they are for you?  They look like this to me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DDHEE.png

Comment: Off-center picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WUtQc.jpg

Comment: @GEdgar, are you using the STIX font, by chance?

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Yes, it says: *Using local STIX fonts* ... Safari 7.0.6

Comment: I used `{\large\bigcirc}\kern-1.55em\iint` to make the circle larger and adjusted the kern a little bit:  $$ {\large\bigcirc}\kern-1.55em\iint $$

Comment: Another option: $$\subset\!\!\supset\kern-1.65em\iint$$ Idea taken from [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5963/21441).

Comment: @Ruslan [That solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUOtQ.jpg) looks suboptimal to me (but in any case, presenting it without the underlying code is pretty unfriendly to novices

Comment: @E.P. the code is two mouse clicks away! But yes, the placement seems system-dependent indeed. MathRenderer→SVG seems to be more consistent though (with its own caveats, of course, like ignoration of custom colors).